# I am confused with the purpose of じゃない in this use case

Tags: grammar

I have heard a native say this sentence about an event:

- 私的にすごい盛り上がって、すごい楽しいイベントになったん**じゃない**かと思います。

I know it's supposed to mean something like: Oh the event became good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works like じゃない in any other context.

> I personally thought, wasn't that a really rousing and fun event.

じゃない is very much like the tag question in English, "wasn't it?" or "isn't it".

A brief note on tense here: since イベントになった is clearly referring to a past event, I've put all the English verbs into the past tense.  To what degree that is correct, really depends on the context.  But for the most part, Japanese isn't as particular about the agreement of *tense* as English.

Comment: " Japanese isn't as particular about the agreement of tense as English." - The way I understand it is that the Japanese tense system is more about *sequencing* events than it is about explicitly temporally locating them (i.e., relative to now).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Among such considerations, I'd been thinking that were you to say と思った then the sense would be more like "I had thought", but perhaps no longer do.  And along those lines, I'd been thinking that じゃなかったか would also have similarly odd *sequencing* effects.  It always seems to me that in a Japanese sentence once past tense has been established, the nonpast forms take on the *flavor* of the past and don't reset the time dial.